# Output to file is different between staging and local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am `print`ing some data to a custom log file. This is the code I am currently using:

> print eco_logger.info("Date: " + Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S") + " | " + "User: " + current_user.email.to_s() + " | " + "Action: Edited User          | User: " + @user.first_name.to_s + " " + @user.last_name.to_s + " | Email: " + @user.email.to_s)

In my local dev environment, it works well. Each print would go on a new line like so:

```
log
log
log
```

However, when I pushed the application to the staging dev server, the log started to print like this:

```
logloglog
```

---

I also tried `\n`, to see if that would work; like so:

> print eco_logger.info("\nDate: " + Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S") + " | " + "User: " + current_user.email.to_s() + " | " + "Action: Edited User          | User: " + @user.first_name.to_s + " " + @user.last_name.to_s + " | Email: " + @user.email.to_s)

Locally, it added another space so things were like this:

```
log

log

log
```

At staging, things remained the same.

---

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this issue?

Comment: How do you inspect the log files?

Comment: I have a link to them in the application. You can click and download the log files and view them on your local computer via your desired text viewer.

Comment: sawa, gosh darnit. you're on an editing frenzy...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built in [logger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) versus your complex print statement?

```
logger.debug "Person attributes hash: #{@person.attributes.inspect}"
logger.info "Processing the request..."
logger.fatal "Terminating application, raised unrecoverable error!!!"
```

Comment: I am using a custom logger because I want it to go to a separate file, in a separate folder. With a different management structure, etc. I thought this may be the only way to do it. If you have another way to do it with the default logger, I would love to know about that (anything to make this easier and more efficient). Thanks !

Comment: Hmmm. Looking at your initial problem description... Sounds like you're setting up some sort of audit. It looks like you might be looking for the functionality of a gem like [Paper Trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail). Also [statsD](http://codeascraft.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/) might work well if you're monitoring something.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you have `eco_logger` set to write to your own log file, then calling `eco_logger.info` should be enough to write a line to the file.

I am not at all sure why you are also using `print` with this, that seems redundant and probably like part of the problem.

Can you explain why you are using both? The `print` by itself like this will print the line to `STDOUT` with no linebreak at the end (that is the difference between `puts` and `print`).

What it looks like is that in development you might be seeing what is written by the `eco_logger.info` statement, which will write with line breaks to the `eco_logger` specified file.

However, on staging I think you are watching some log where the `print` output to `STDOUT` is captured, which does not include line breaks.

Comment: Ah okay, this clarification is really helping me. I guess I don't understand the functionality of the logging system in rails. I've just been reading examples and docs and trying to put things together. So why would the staged server be interpreting this differently? To note, I'm going to try your suggestions and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Good overview here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

Comment: You can update the config of your logs to go to a different file, and then just use the default logger. You could also create a softlink from the default location to wherever the file is you are serving up as a url.  If you do expose your logs this way, be sure you filter sensitive params in case they get exposed: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#logging

Comment: BTW - if what you want is to have an easy way to look at your logs, there are services that do this, like this one which is a heroku plugin as well: https://logentries.com/

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I will look into this all. In regards to my current issue. I tried removing the `print` and just made it so it was like ` eco_logger.info("\nDate: " + Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S") + " | " + "User: " + current_user.email.to_s() + " | " + "Action: Edited User | User: " + @user.first_name.to_s + " " + @user.last_name.to_s + " | Email: " + @user.email.to_s)` This however did not work. I also tried a `puts` in front too. Nothing changed with that either....